# How to use Template Parameter at Case Classes

Tags: scala, generics

I have a question about Template parameters in Scala with Case Classes.

First working scenario then what I try to achive

```
object Test1 {
    sealed trait Response
    final case class StateResponse(state : Any) extend Response
}

abstract class Test1[STATE] {
    def something() : Unit = {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now if use this in the following

```
import Test1._ 

result match {
   case StateResponse(state) => ...
   case _ => ...
}
```

Everything works fine but probably see what disturbs me, 'Any' at StateResponse. Depending on the implementation class I would like to have concrete State Type then any so..

```
object Test1Impl {
     sealed trait State
     final case class Test1State(payload: Map[String, String])
```

}

```
class Test1Impl extends Test1[Test1State] {
}
```

as you might guess I can't use Template parameter in Test1 in Object Definition but I thought, if I define the case class in class definition, it might work....

```
object Test1 {
   sealed trait Response 
}

abstract class Test1[STATE] {
   final case class StateResponse(state : STATE) extends Response
   
   def something() : Unit = {
      .....
   }
}
```

now until now, Scala Compiler does not complain about anything but when I try

```
import Test1._

result match {
   case StateResponse(state) => ...
   case _ => ...
}
```

then it can't locate 'StateResponse' at case statement and 'Test1.StateResponse' is not helping, so I am doing something illegal, but what?

Or can you tell me how can I make this work?

Thx for answers....

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make `StateResponse` generic rather than enclosing class

```
final case class StateResponse[STATE](state : STATE) extends Response
```

Otherwise, when you make `Test1` generic, an instance of `StateResponse` starts to depend on an instance of `Test1`

```
val t = new Test1[Int] {} // you made Test1 abstract, so I had to write {}

val result = t.StateResponse(10)
result match {
  case t.StateResponse(state) => println("1")
  case _ => println("2")
}
```

or

```
import t._

val result = StateResponse(10)
result match {
  case StateResponse(state) => println("1")
  case _ => println("2")
}
```